# How to give View Only permission to all by default in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Requirement:
Everyone over the Internet should have *View Only* permission by default.

[image: No Anonymous Accesslink]

Comment: These type of questions should go on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Turn on anonymous access on web application in Central Administration
2. Turn on anonymous access entire web.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/grant-permissions-to-anonymous-users-HA101805390.aspx

Comment: I don't have Anonymous link on Ribbion.

Comment: Firstly, you have to enable anonymous access in Central Administration: http://www.sharepointkris.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=2

Comment: Thanks. I am now able to do.